# How Call link tag by id by javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
   <img src="images/icon2.png" border=0 onClick="window.document.getElementById('loadimg')">

<a href="images/img.jpg" id='loadimg'></a>
```

i want when click the image will active the link by id='loadimg'
how can i do i try write onClick="window.document.getElementById('loadimg')" but not work

Than you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want the item in the link to be loaded so something like this should work:

```
window.location.href = window.document.getElementById('loadimg').href;
```

This will cause the broswer page to navigate to this url.

Or was there something else you wanted to do?

Answer (score 3):

You can put the image in the link:

```
<a href="images/img.jpg" id='loadimg'>
    <img src="images/icon2.png" border="0" />    
</a>
```

Comment: Exactly! I can't find a reason why an image cannot be wrapped by an anchor. Is there one?

Comment: no i want to load slider by parent image(album) and when click image album will load slider with all image when put image inside link will show all imae but i not this